# Differentiation of Woocommerce Quantity Input Value by Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I check the minimum quantity of my products and the increasing steps with the code below. Now I have decided to work with different product categories, and this code that I applied to the entire site is not suitable for new products. How can I differentiate the values by category?

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 100;  // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }
    $args['max_value']  = 10000;    // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 100;      // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 50;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

// Variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 10000;       // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 100;     // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```